# How to two data frame using contain or regexp condition

Tags: r, join

I have 2 data.frame

```
id            country
 1    United State
 2  United Kingdom
 3          Russia
 4      Belorussia
```

and

```
group_condition   group
         United  group1
           Russ  group2
```

And I would like to get this

```
id         country  group
 1    United State  group1
 2  United Kingdom  group1
 3          Russia  group2
 4      Belorussia  group2
```

How I can do this?

Comment: Site note. These are countries, not cities.

Comment: edit, how i can merge data?

Answer (score 1):

Kind of ugly, but works:

```
temp = sapply(group_condition,grepl,x=country,ignore.case=T)
new_group_col = group[max.col(temp)]
```

Comment: what is "group" and "country"?its colname?

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it this way though a more elegant solution probably exists

```
id_c <- data.frame(id = 1:4, country = c("United State","United Kingdome","Russia","Belorussia"))
gc_g <- data.frame(group_condition = c("United","Russ"), group = c("group1","group2"))

# first find the rows that match the expressions
matches <- lapply(gc_g$group_condition,grep,id_c$country,ignore.case=T)

# then for each of them add the group condition to the first table
for (i in 1:nrow(gc_g)){
  id_c$group[matches[[i]]] <- gc_g$group_condition[i]
}
```